# Rails Adding to Array When Slug is Matched

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

I am new to Rails as a UI Engineer and looking for some help with Rails and Querying the DB --

I have an array of strings (email addresses) that I wanted to match within Activerecord via Rails Console. If each user in the user table matches one of the email addresses in the array, I wanted to apply add a product id to that user.

What's the best way to do this as a quick one-time add via Rails Production Console? I have the following pseudo code.

```
gift = 800
emails = [email addresses, ...]

User.where(email: [emails]).each_do |user|
   user.products ADD gift (to array products within user table)
end
```

Comment: It Products a model? I.e. User has_many products? Or is products a text string stored as a serialized array? It doesn't make much difference to my answer below. Only, if products is an associated model, then gift needs to be an instance of Product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
User.where(email: [emails]).find_each do |user|
  user.products << gift unless user.products.include? gift
  user.save
end
```